# jQuery Datatable Get custom ajax parameters

Tags: datatables

I have my jQuery Datatable and I add some custom ajax params in `fnServerData` function:

```
"fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {

    aoData.push({
        name: "selection",
        value: 123456
    });

    oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
        "dataType": "json",
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": function(data) {

            if (data.selection === false) {
                hideWaiting();
            }

            fnCallback(data);

        },
        "error": function(jqXHR, txtStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(txtStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
},
```

In other function I need to get all the ajax params:

```
var ajaxParams = table.ajax.params();
```

I can get here all the `datatable` ajax params but I can't find my `selection` custom parameter.

[image]

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're performing your own Ajax request, and because of that I'm assuming that jQuery DataTables is unaware of the changes you make to `aoData` array after it has been passed to your own function.

The easiest workaround would be to store `aoData` in a global variable and access it when you need the last request parameters.

Otherwise you may need to use [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) and [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) initialization options to let jQuery DataTables handle Ajax request itself. That way it would know the custom parameters that were added in function defined by [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option.

Comment: Amazing... you are totally right!! Never tought about it.